# Start Kubernetes job from within service

Tags: kubernetes

I'm kinda new to Kubernets and I think I understand the basics of the whole system but most of the stuff I have read was about how to use kubectl to start a service and deployment and stuff.

But in my use case I have this web API running (built in ASP.net core) that takes a request, does some processing and depending on the input data has to start a secondary process.

A Kubernetes job with restart policy OnFailure seemed to be the way to implement those secondary processes but I can't find any resources on how the web server can be used to start this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Kubernetes API to create a Job(or any kubernetes resource) from your application running inside the cluster. You can either install `kubectl` inside your applications's container and call it from your application code or use a kubernetes client library(https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp) to talk to kubernetes API server.

See the following answer for more details:

[Kubernetes - Finding out how many replicas there are in a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59682162/kubernetes-finding-out-how-many-replicas-there-are-in-a-service/59682581#59682581)

Comment: the dotnet api seems to work, thanks! Had to create a cluster role binding though:  
`kubectl create clusterrolebinding --user system:serviceaccount:default:default default-cluster-admin --clusterrole cluster-admin`